# How many edits can I approve in a day?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I just got this message when trying to approve an edit:

> Out of votes - you may not vote on this user any more today.

How many approvals do I get?  It seems really low (3?)

Note, I'm interested in per-person approvals and overall approvals as well.

Comment: My original plan was to link you to [the general info post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work), but it seems that the actual numbers are absent in favor of "There is a limit". But for the record, the original number during an earlier test phase was precisely "3".

Comment: @Grace, I looked at that post too and didn't see the info I wanted.

Comment: As mentioned, you can't find what's not there, after all.

Comment: @Grace, yup.  Just mentioning that we were thinking on the same lines I guess.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, this is very low by design to avoid gaming. At the moment the per-person limit is set to 3 and the global limit is set to 30 ([50 on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129894/152859)).

Comment: Wishing this were higher. (Also wish I weren't notified for edits I can't approve.)  But thanks for posting the numbers here.

Comment: @jjnguy I will see if I can exclude notification of wiki edits from 10k-20k users .. don't want to run expensive queries on every page ... we can always tweak this number up if needed

Comment: I just ran into this too, three per user is disconcerting, because the excerpt and wiki equals two votes, both inevitably by the same user, which leaves you with half a wiki entry approved / rejected if the user posts twice.

Comment: Perhaps the number of per user edit votes could go up on a per 10K rep basis?

Comment: Could you edit the current numbers into this question, please?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd it has been [changed to 50 on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117903/158951), but I still ran into that limit 10 minutes ago. 125 suggested edits at the moment and I am not allowed to work on it for the rest of the day!

Comment: @stema yeah, saw that after posting the comment. Will update this answer now. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Out of votes - you may only vote 40 times a day

This seems very low when there is a badge to encourage approving / rejecting edits. Perhaps reputation or previous badges could be reckoned when setting the limit on this particular activity?

Comment: There is also a badge for upvoting 600 questions w/ 25% of votes on questions. Yet you can only vote max 40 times a day. Your point? If you could earn a badge in 5 minutes by incessant clicking, then its a badge not worth earning at all, just like the `Autobiographer/Analyst/Suffrage/Vox Populi/Critic/Editor/Commentator/Supporter/Student/Teacher/CleanupOrganizer/Citizen Patrol/many-more-this-list-is-too-long` badges. Those are meant merely to introduce you to the SE engine. Sophisticated badges require more time. Be patient :)

Comment: @yoda I am not interested in earning badges for editing and was surprised when I got one. I am deeply saddened that all you can see in my post is a whine about badges and miss my intention, which was to speed up the approval process. It is a tedious enough job, which I do not always feel like doing, and it is made more tedious by limiting the number of approvals / rejects to 40.