# How many times 2000+ rep rep user can approve suggested edit on a daily basis?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How many edits can I approve in a day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77763/how-many-edits-can-i-approve-in-a-day)

Someone said

> There is a limitation to the number of times you may vote on a single user's suggestions. \

What is the limit, that a 2,000+ rep user can approve a suggested edit of the same person?

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77763/how-many-edits-can-i-approve-in-a-day